# Is there a way to invoke the ANSI ATA enhanced secure erase command targeting an SSD after booting into Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, secure-erase

I'm too lazy to burn a bootable image, and then wait for the wiping to occur.

To securely (in terms of lack of recoverability and safety to the SSD) wipe a Crucial M4 SSD. Is there a DOS command or a program out there that will do the job?

This is my old boot drive (i.e., C:), but I have already cloned it to a different disk (the one I am writing this post from).